# Smooth Scroll going to the same top anchor

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem where my smooth scroll jquery is going to the same anchor each time...here is my code:

```
<a href="#ax">a</a>
<a href="#b">a</a>
Takes you too...
<a name="ax" id="ax"></a>
<a name="b" id="b"></a>

$('a[href*=#]').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
}, 500);
return false;
});
```

Its to take you to each letter in the alphabet (I named a ax just in case a was getting mixed with < a > etc). So the problem is that it always goes to a.

I feel like the jquery isnt the problem and I'm just missing a concept!

Many thanks

Comment: can you create jsfiddlr for it

Answer (score 0):

use this more optimized function for smooth scroll

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hmm damn that didnt work, completely stops the smooth animation now :(

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle for your code I will try to fix.